# jdbc connection to oracle using type 2

Tags: java, jdbc

I got a problem when connecting to oracle db 11g using java jdbc ..
Tns  no listener SQLexception will arise then

```
Conncetion con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@ORCL","scott","tiger");
```

Answer (score 0):

If get like this problem then goto

- services.msc 
  Restart all oracle service's